# How can I add bounties for my question

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I have 111 reputations and want to add 50 bounties for my this question: [pfSense not forwarding DNS to concerned VPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/744029/pfsense-not-forwarding-dns-to-concerned-vps)

Please advise how can I add them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read https://serverfault.com/help/bounty

The important part for you:

> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

This means you just can't add a bounty to your question less then an hour old yet.

In my opinion: Save your rep points and use them to participate in the site.  Bounties are not worth the hassle.

Comment: I am seeing this link at end of my question `question eligible for bounty in 2 days' but when I click it then it refers me to this link: http://serverfault.com/help/bounty.. I am not seeing drop down menu as stated in  this link: http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: @Ghayel - Well, did you wait 2 days? (Bonus info: No you didn't ;)) Sometime tomorrow you should be able to put a bounty on the question. Also agreeing on the bounty stuff Sven mentioned.